# Rails & MySQL - How do I use the LIKE operator with % in find_by_sql in rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, find-by-sql

How do I remove the quotation marks around a variable so that I can use the LIKE operator in find_by_sql in rails?

```
@entries1 = Entry.find_by_sql(["SELECT `entries`.name as name FROM `entries` where `entries`.name like '%?%'",@something])
```

will yield

```
SELECT `entries`.name as name FROM `entries` where `entries`.name like '%'hello'%'
```

when `@something = 'hello'`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of putting the percent symbols in the SQL, add them to the variable you're injecting (after escaping percent signs/underscores already present!)

```
"%#{@something.gsub('%', '\%').gsub('_', '\_')}%"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `concat` inside the database:

```
Entry.find_by_sql([
  "SELECT ... `entries`.name like concat('%', ?, '%')",
  @something
])
```

or you can add the wildcards in Ruby:

```
Entry.find_by_sql([
  "SELECT ... `entries`.name like ?",
  "%#{@something}"
])
```

Note that other databases will want to see `'%' || ? || '%'` or `'%' + ? + '%'` instead of the `concat` call.

Answer (score 2):

`@entries1 = Entry.select('name').where('name like ?',"%#{@something}%"])` should do the same

Answer (score 1):

You need four '%' around the search value and must precede each with delimiter ‘\’.

For example search_val can be “” or “031”, etc...

```
find_by_sql([ "select  * from tableX where id like '\%\%#{search_val}\%\%'" ])
```